# sql query maximum cummulative

Tags: mysql, sql, max, cumulative-sum

i have table A in mysql

```
+-------------------------+
| ID  Name Month  Salary  |
+-------------------------+
| 1  Joe   4      300     |
| 2  Kim   3     100      |
| 3  Moko  2     150      |
| 4   Loli  5     80      |
| 5  Tom   3    400       |
+-------------------------+
```

how do i get total number of salary based on month and the person who earned max

**example**

```
Joe = 4*300 = 1200
Kim = 300
Moko = 300
Loli = 400
Tom = 1200
```

**The output will be** : 1200, 2

1200 is the max salary and 2 is people who earned which is Joe and Tom

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: already edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute all the `total` salaries in a subquery, then count the number of occurrences of each `total` value, ordering by the `total` descending with a `LIMIT 1` to restrict to the highest value:

```
SELECT total, COUNT(*) AS num
FROM (
  SELECT Month * Salary AS total
  FROM data
) t
GROUP BY total
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Output:

```
total   num
1200    2
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53b9d0/2)

Answer (score 2):

try like below using subquery

```
    select max(salary),count(*) from (select name, sum(Month*Salary) as salary
    from data    group by name
    ) b where b.salary= 

   (select max(salary) from
   (select sum(Month*Salary) as salary
    from data    group by name
    )b
    )
```

[Demo link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4534f6/10)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Month*Salary, COUNT(*)
FROM A WHERE Month*Salary = (SELECT MAX(Month*Salary)
                             FROM A)
```

The second query will give you the maximum total salary earned and then you can filter the entries in table A with Month*Salary being equal to that amount.